# Facebook API sdk 4.0 - post a photo onto facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am trying to create an application where the user can browse and submit a photo from their computer onto their facebook. For this, they will first have to upload their photo onto the server and then using a facebook request, post this image onto facebook. I am using multipart/form-data.

This is what I have so far for this, assuming I have a valid session, my api request:

```
$request = new Facebook{
$session,
'POST',
'/me/photos',
array (
    'source' => '{image-data}',
    )
    );
    $response = $request->execute();
    $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
    /* handle the result*/
```

I am not sure what to replace image-data with.

For the uploading photo, my code is as follows:

```
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$file_type = $_FILES['file']['type']; //returns the file type

$allowed = array("image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png", "image/jpg"); //specifies allowed file types
if(!in_array($file_type, $allowed)) {
        $error_message = 'Only jpeg, jpg, gif, and png files are allowed. <br> 
        Please click back and try again.';
        echo $error_message;

        exit();
    }

$name       = $_FILES['file']['name'];  //original path of the uploaded file
$temp_name  = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];  //contains the path to the temporary file that resides on the server
if(isset($name)){
    if(!empty($name)){      
        $location = 'uploads/'; //save photo to the folder: uploads
        if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $location.$name)){
            echo 'Photo was successfully uploaded.';
        }
    }       
}  else {
    echo 'Photo was unsuccessfully uploaded, click back and try again.';
 }
 }
```

I am new to facebook api, and a novice at coding. Any help or advice will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Whole code:

```
     <?php

  require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php' );
  require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' );
  require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );

  require_once( 'Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php' );
  require_once( 'Facebook/Entities/SignedRequest.php' );
  require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
  require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
  require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
  require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
  require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
  require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
  require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookServerException.php' );
  require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookOtherException.php' );
  require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
  require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
  require_once( 'Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );


  use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
  use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurl;
  use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;

  use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
  use Facebook\Entities\SignedRequest;
  use Facebook\FacebookSession;
  use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
  use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
  use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
  use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
  use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
  use Facebook\FacebookServerException;
  use Facebook\FacebookOtherException;
  use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
  use Facebook\GraphObject;
  use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;


 // start session
 session_start();

// init app with app id and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( 'xxxxxxxxxx','xxxxxxxxxxxxx' );

// login helper with redirect_uri
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'https://apps.facebook.com/myapp' );

// see if a existing session exists
if ( isset( $_SESSION ) && isset( $_SESSION['fb_token'] ) ) {
    // create new session from saved access_token
    $session = new FacebookSession( $_SESSION['fb_token'] );

// validate the access_token to make sure it's still valid
try {
    if ( !$session->validate() ) {
    $session = null;
    }
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
// catch any exceptions
$session = null;
    }
}     

if ( !isset( $session ) || $session === null ) {
    // no session exists

try {
$session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
    } catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
    // When Facebook returns an error
    // handle this better in production code
        print_r( $ex );
            } catch( Exception $ex ) {
// When validation fails or other local issues
// handle this better in production code
    print_r( $ex );
}

}

// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) {

// save the session
$_SESSION['fb_token'] = $session->getToken();
// create a session using saved token or the new one we generated at login
$session = new FacebookSession( $session->getToken() );

// graph api request for user data
$request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
$response = $request->execute();
// get response
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();



// print logout url using session and redirect_uri (destroy the session)
echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLogoutUrl( $session, 'http://localhost/app/index.php', session_destroy() ) .    '">Logout</a>';

} else {
  // show login url
  echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl( array( 'email', 'user_friends', 'publish_actions' ) ) . '">Login</a>';

}


 ?>

  <html>
     <head>
        <title> My App</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div>


    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Please select a photo to upload <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">

    </form>
    </div>

   </body>
 </html>
 <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type']; //returns the file type

    $allowed = array("image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png", "image/jpg"); //specifies allowed file types
    if(!in_array($file_type, $allowed)) {
        $error_message = 'Only jpeg, jpg, gif, and png files are allowed. <br> 
        Please click back and try again.';
        echo $error_message;

        exit();
    }

     $name       = $_FILES['file']['name'];  //original path of the uploaded file
     $temp_name  = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];  //contains the path to the temporary file that resides on the server
     if(isset($name)){
     if(!empty($name)){      
        $location = 'uploads/'; //save photo to the folder: uploads
        if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $location.$name)){
            echo 'Photo was successfully uploaded.';
        }
    }       
 }  else {
    echo 'Photo was unsuccessfully uploaded, click back and try again.';
 }

$session = new FacebookSession( $_SESSION['fb_token']);
$request = new FacebookRequest(
 $session,
 'POST',
 '/me/photos',
 array (
    'source' => file_get_contents($location.$name),
 )
 );

  $response = $request->execute();
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
    print_r($response);
  }

    $token = $_GET['code'];
    echo $token;


     ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, there are two main issues with your code.

**FIRST**:

Remove `session_destroy()` from your code. It's the reason why the session is being deleted. You can then remove the second use of `$session = new FacebookSession( $_SESSION['fb_token']);` from your code. You only need to do that bit once!

Change:

```
echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLogoutUrl( $session, 'http://localhost/app/index.php', session_destroy() ) .    '">Logout</a>';
```

to

```
echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLogoutUrl( $session, 'http://localhost/app/index.php' ) .    '">Logout</a>';
```

**SECOND**:

Append `@` to your `source` and you will find that the image uploads correctly. E.g.:

```
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'POST',
  '/me/photos',
  array (
    'source' => new CURLFile( $location.$name ),
  )
);
```

`CURLFile` only works on PHP 5.5+. For earlier version of PHP, set source to:

```
'source' => '@' . $location.$name
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I still get errors:
Deprecated: curl_setopt_array(): The usage of the @filename API for file uploading is deprecated. Please use the CURLFile class instead in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurl.php on line 66

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Facebook\FacebookSDKException' with message 'couldn't open file "uploads/983710_10154252423865510_7686584102535451506_n.jpg"' in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\Facebook\HttpClients......................

Comment: I've updated my answer to use CURLFile instead. Also, make sure the uploads folder and file has correct permissions to allow reading. I tested the CURLFile version and it works for me.

Comment: I get this error: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Facebook\FacebookSDKException' with message 'couldn't open file "uploads/983710_10154252423865510_7686584102535451506_n.jpg"' in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient.php:142 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\Facebook\FacebookRequest.php(248): Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient->send('https://graph.f...', 'POST', Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\index.php(180): Facebook\FacebookRequest->execute() #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient.php on line 142.

Comment: I've checked the permissions, read is allowed for both the folder and the file.... do you know any other reason why it isn't working for me? And thank you for changing the answer to use CURLFILE, I couldn't figure out how to put my variables as the parameters.

Comment: It could be that the PHP CURL extension is missing and it's using the Facebook client instead, which could be causing issues. Verify that CURL is enabled.

Comment: I just checked (with the help of this link: http://www.mattsbits.co.uk/item-164.html) CURL is enabled on my server.

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions? :( I have no idea where to even start to solve this. Nothing online about this error, I don't get why it is throwing this error. :(

Comment: Having looked at the FacebookCurlHttpClient code.. I think it is my ssl certificate causing the problem with CURL.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the user has correctly uploaded the image and `$location.$name` is the path:

```
 $request = new FacebookRequest(
     $session,
     'POST',
     '/me/photos',
     array (
        'source' => file_get_contents($location.$name),
     )
  );

 $response = $request->execute();
 $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
```

Or another possibility is via URL:

```
 $request = new FacebookRequest(
   $session,
   'POST',
   '/me/photos',
   array (
     'url' => $the_url_to_the_image,
   )
 );

 $response = $request->execute();
 $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
```

And the API call you do AFTER the upload is done by the user but that is not more than logical.

Comment: I thought the syntax was new CURLFIle...? Anyway I tried that. I did the api request inside the last two curly brackets of uploading photo code but I get an error: Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Facebook\FacebookRequest::__construct() must be an instance of Facebook\FacebookSession, null given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\index.php on line 180 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\Facebook\FacebookRequest.php on line 182. I also get the same error when I place it outside and after the submit/upload code.

Comment: It can't be a session problem because I was able to post a message on my feed..?

Comment: $session is not set than. Are you able to show the whole code?

Comment: Hmm.. but I was able to post a message? But yeah, I'll post the whole code. :) Thanks for your time

Comment: Another thing I am confused about is when I load the page via my local host url. I click login and you can see the code in my url and the log out button appears. I browse and upload a picture, and the log out button goes back to being login. Now when I click on it, I get directed to a blank page. I am so confused.