# Facebook api sdk 4.0 php 5.5 - Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Facebook\FacebookSDKException' - can't upload photo to facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am trying to implement an app that allows the user to choose a photo from their computer to upload onto facebook via my app. For the full code, please refer to: [Facebook API sdk 4.0 - post a photo onto facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24885784/facebook-api-sdk-4-0-post-a-photo-onto-facebook/24914571#24914571)

My code seems to be right - user uploads a photo via the form onto the server and then an API request is sent to POST the photo onto facebook, however I have this error:

```
   Uncaught exception 'Facebook\FacebookSDKException' with message 'couldn't open file   
   "uploads/10419411_10152352973347745_2810638062953115781_n.jpg"' in      
   C:\xampp\htdocs\app\Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient.php:142 Stack trace: #0
   C:\xampp\htdocs\app\Facebook\FacebookRequest.php(248): Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient-
   >send('https://graph.f...', 'POST', Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\index.php(180): Facebook\FacebookRequest-
   >execute() #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient.php on line 142
```

CURL is enabled. And my folder and file's permissions are readable. I really have no idea what this error means. I looked at line 142 in FacebookCurlHttpClient, and it's to do with curlErrorCode. Does anyone know what this means and how to fix?

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: Hi, my code is shown in a previous post of mine, please have a look at this link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24885784/facebook-api-sdk-4-0-post-a-photo-onto-facebook/24914571#24914571

Comment: That looks like the documentation. What does your code look like?

Comment: What do you mean? The link provided links to my code :/ I've included it in my question under "Whole code" :) apparently someone tested my code out and it worked, so I have no idea at all why it isn't working for me and why it is throwing that error..

Comment: You linked to the first comment. That why I didn't see it. The problem is that you are not following the documentation. As the first comment say source should not be the content of the file

Comment: Hello, thank you for having a look. I'm sorry for the confusion, didn't realise the link was to the first comment. Anyway, what do you mean the 'source should not be the content of the file'? Do you think you can provide me with the change to fix the problem? I am new to programming in general and to facebook api... so I'm confused by what the problem is.

Comment: @WizKid I have already made the changes advised in the first comment of that question.. yet I still get the error.

Answer (score 2):

Check the permissions of your upload folder on the server and make sure your script can read the files in there. Try `chmod 755 *` on the folder to enable read permissions for all files and see if that fixes your issue.

If that doesn't work, try change the permission of the file after you upload it to the server using PHP, but before you upload it to Facebook.

Comment: Thank you. I have solved this problem. The problem was my path, I didn't have the full path - instead I just had /uploads/. This is what I changed it to and it worked  $location = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/app/uploads/';