# cURL error when making a facebook api request due to SSL? PHP, SDK 4.0, using XAMPP

Tags: php, curl, openssl, xampp, facebook-sdk-4.0

Took me a while to figure out why my code, as mentioned in a previous post: [Facebook API sdk 4.0 - post a photo onto facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24885784/facebook-api-sdk-4-0-post-a-photo-onto-facebook) wasn't working, and gave me the following errors:

```
  Uncaught exception 'Facebook\FacebookSDKException' with message 'couldn't open file   
  "uploads/10419411_10152352973347745_2810638062953115781_n.jpg"' in      
  C:\xampp\htdocs\app\Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient.php:142 Stack trace: #0
  C:\xampp\htdocs\app\Facebook\FacebookRequest.php(248): Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient-
  >send('https://graph.f...', 'POST', Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\index.php(180): Facebook\FacebookRequest-
  >execute() #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient.php on line 142
```

I am using XAMPP, and running my app on my local host. To this, due to facebook making their secure browsing default, I had to use their inbuilt openssl to create a self signed certificate. As before, the page was blank but now my content shows.

I am trying to create an application where the user can upload a photo from their computer onto facebook. When making the api request using CURL:

```
      $request = new FacebookRequest(
        $session,
        'POST',
        '/me/photos',
         array (
        'source' => new CURLFile( $location.$name ),
         )
      );
```

I get the above error. Looking at FacebookCurlHttpClient.php it appears that it is curl_error code 60 and 77 - relating to ssl causing the code to not work. I really am confused with the whole SSL. I thought I had it sorted with creating my own self signed certificate and all.. can some please advise me on what to do to fix this problem??